# How to inject something onto the window object before load using Nightwatch JS?

Tags: nightwatch.js

Cypress has the concept of the following:

```
cy.on("window:before:load", (win) => {
  win.myObj = {} // something 
});
```

What is the equivalent of this in Nightwatch JS?

Comment: are these kind of global variables?

Comment: Yes, its a global variable on the window object that I want to set before the test runs in Nightwatch JS.

Comment: Did you check this? https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/execute.html